# Stripe connect integration with Django

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments, payment, environment

I'm new integrating stripe in django but lately, I've been having an error that I just can't find the answer to it, every time that I try to connect the stripe account to my website, this error appears:

{"error":{"message":"No application matches the supplied client identifier"}}

Here's the code:

```
import urllib

import requests

from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views import View
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect

from .models import Seller


class StripeAuthorizeView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))
        url = 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize'
        params = {
            'response_type': 'code',
            'scope': 'read_write',
            'client_id': settings.STRIPE_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID,
            'redirect_uri': f'http://localhost:8000/users/oauth/callback'
        }
        url = f'{url}?{urllib.parse.urlencode(params)}'
        return redirect(url)


class StripeAuthorizeCallbackView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        code = request.GET.get('code')
        if code:
            data = {
                'client_secret': settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY,
                'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
                'client_id': settings.STRIPE_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID,
                'code': code
            }
            url = 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token'
            resp = requests.post(url, params=data)
            # add stripe info to the seller
            stripe_user_id = resp.json()['stripe_user_id']
            stripe_access_token = resp.json()['access_token']
            seller = Seller.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id).first()
            seller.stripe_access_token = stripe_access_token
            seller.stripe_user_id = stripe_user_id
            seller.save()
        url = reverse('home')
        response = redirect(url)
        return response
```

settings.py

```
STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = '<your test publishable key here>'
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = '<your test secret key here>'
STRIPE_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID = '<your test connect client id here>'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using params=data when you should be using data=data:

```
       data = {
            'client_secret': settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY,
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'client_id': settings.STRIPE_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID,
            'code': code
        }
        url = 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token'
        #resp = requests.post(url, params=data)
        resp = requests.post(url, data=data) #Try with this instead
```

from the requests documentation, params are for Url parameters:
You often want to send some sort of data in the **URL’s query string**. If you were constructing the URL by hand, this data would be given as key/value pairs in the URL after a question mark, e.g. **httpbin.org/get?key=val**. Requests allows you to provide these arguments as a dictionary of strings, **using the params keyword argument**.

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/

And for the data=data part, also from the same page:
Requests’ simple API means that all forms of HTTP request are as obvious. For example, **this is how you make an HTTP POST request**:

```
>>> r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your answer, but I didn't understand very well the last part

Comment: which part ? what you need to do is to use resp = requests.post(url, data=data) instead of 
resp = requests.post(url, params=data)